# $fseek not reading byte in hex file

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I cannot seem to read the 4th byte in a hex file:

```
 module file_read();
   integer fd,file_char;
   logic [7:0] captured_data;

   initial begin
        fd = $fopen("README.lz4", "rb");
        while (!$feof(fd)) begin
               file_char=$fseek(fd,5,0);
               $display("file char is %h",file_char);
       end
    end
endmodule
```

File contents are...

```
 00000000  04 22 4d 18 64 40 a7 43....
 .........
```

Comment: Yes that is why I was reading the file in hex.Is that not possible?

Comment: @coding_gal You should be able to hit (edit) underneath your post, so you can edit the actual post to remove the comments. You should also tell us what *does* happen when you run your program.

Answer (score 1):

`$fseek` does not read a character from a file, it merely specifies where in the file the character should be read from. Instead, you could use `$fgetc`:

```
module file_read();
   integer fd,file_char,status;
   logic [7:0] captured_data;

   initial begin
        fd = $fopen("README.lz4", "rb");
        status=$fseek(fd,4,0);
        while (!$feof(fd)) begin
          file_char=$fgetc(fd);
          $display("file char is %h",file_char);
       end
    end
endmodule
```

So, I have moved the call to `$fseek` outside the loop - we only want to do this once given the format you have described. I have also changed the offset to 4, assuming you wanted to skip over the `00000000`. I have changed the variable assigned to by the return value of `$fseek` to `status`, because that is what is returned from `$fseek`:

> 0 for success, -1 for error

Also, `$fgetc` returns a `-1` to signify the end of the file. So, you perhaps want to change your `while` loop to a `do` `while` loop and test the value of `file_char` at the end (and get rid of `$feof`) eg

```
module file_read();
   integer fd,file_char,status;
   logic [7:0] captured_data;

   initial begin
        fd = $fopen("README.lz4", "rb");
        status=$fseek(fd,4,0);
        assert (status);
        do begin
          file_char=$fgetc(fd);
          $display("file char is %h",file_char);
        end
        while (file_char != -1); 
    end
endmodule
```

(I have not tested either of these two blocks of code given the lack of a file to test them on.)